# can't ssh on linux ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat

I'm trying to ssh into a red hat 7 linux server and I am unable to. I am getting an error:

```
ssh companyadmin@10.48.216.147
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 62: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p 22 10.48.216.147
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1990975652
debug1: identity file /home/tdunphy/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/tdunphy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/tdunphy/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/tdunphy/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/tdunphy/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/tdunphy/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/tdunphy/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/tdunphy/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I've checked my permissions on my client side and they seem good:

```
[tdunphy@bastion-server01 ~]$ ls -ld .ssh
drwx------. 2 tdunphy tdunphy 58 Aug 12 17:34 .ssh
[tdunphy@bastion-server01 ~]$ ls -lh .ssh/*
-rw-------. 1 tdunphy tdunphy  408 Sep 11  2018 .ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 tdunphy tdunphy 1.7K Aug 12 17:20 .ssh/id_rsa
-rw-------. 1 tdunphy tdunphy  408 Aug 12 17:34 .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

This is the sshd_config from the server I'm trying to ssh from:

```
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
KerberosAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
ClientAliveInterval 900
ClientAliveCountMax 0
IgnoreRhosts yes
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
Banner /etc/issue
PermitUserEnvironment no
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
```

There is nothing in `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`.

I tried doing a `restorecon -v /home/tdunphy/.ssh` but that didn't do any good.

What can I do to log into the remote machine?

Comment: Check the logs on the server in `/var/log/secure` to find out what is happening.

Comment: When i try to ssh that doesn't generate any activity in `/var/log/secure`. I've updated the OP with that information and what else I've tried. Thanks.

Comment: Are you connecting to the right host, then? If nothing was logged, then you weren't connecting to that server.

Comment: Yes. I am. I just remembered these are Azure servers I am dealing with. So I am going to try to get a serial console on the machine I'm trying to log into to get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: You need to check `/var/log/secure` on the server you are trying to reach, not the one you are connecting from.

Comment: OK, understood thanks. I'm unable to get a console on the remote machine. I'll have to find someone who has the password, as none of mine work. :(